# Procedure loop to store an inputted number into an array of integers

Tags: c++, loops, menu, storage

I am trying to call up this procedure in my main program with a menu and only type one number in and then go back to the main program. I also want to store this number in an array so that if I want I can put multiple numbers in the array and keep them in their indexes.

```
void procedure1(int Num1[], int size = 10)
{
   for (int x = 0; x < size; x++)
   {
       cout << "Input a number: ";
       cin >> Num1[x];
   }

}
```

It out puts "Input a number" 10 times and I only want it to do it once, but store the first number in Num1[0], and the next inputted number in Num1[1]... and so on until Num1[10]

Comment: Look at `cin.ignore()`, or (I'd suggest) using `std::getline()` instead of reading mixed types from stdin

Answer (score 1):

You can address this with *proper* use of `cin.ignore()`, but that's honestly more complicated than it's worth many times, and *sometimes* it's not even possible.

My suggestion is to always read in data as strings, then validate the input afterward.  Here's an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    
    for(int x = 0; x < 10; ++x)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter a number:\n";
        
        std::string in;
        std::getline(cin, in);
        
        int num = 0;
        std::istringstream ss{in};
        
        // Validate input here
        if(ss >> num)
        {
            std::cout << "Entered: " << num << '\n';
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Invalid Nuber!" << '\n';
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Given this input:

```
10
20
30
NOT A NUMBER
40
50
60
70
80
90
```

Gives this output:

```
Enter a number:
Entered: 10
Enter a number:
Entered: 20
Enter a number:
Entered: 30
Enter a number:
Invalid Nuber!
Enter a number:
Entered: 40
Enter a number:
Entered: 50
Enter a number:
Entered: 60
Enter a number:
Entered: 70
Enter a number:
Entered: 80
Enter a number:
Entered: 90
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use "C" Style arrays but use `std::vector` like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

bool is_valid_input(const std::string& input)
{
    for (const auto c : input)
    {
        if (!std::isdigit(c)) return false;
    }

    return true;
}

std::vector<int> get_user_input()
{
    std::vector<int>  values;
    std::string input;

    do
    {
        std::cout << "Enter digits : ";
        std::cin >> input;
    } while (!is_valid_input(input));

    for(const auto c : input)
    {
        values.push_back(static_cast<int>(c-'0'));
    }

    return values;
}

int main()
{
    auto values = get_user_input();

    for(const int value : values)
    {
        std::cout << value << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```